# MongoDB / Mongoose: find(query) and aggregate([ $match: query ]) results differ when using dates and $gte / $lte

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use Mongoose to build an aggregation pipeline and the match works fine until I want to match dates using `$gte` and `$lte` operators. The weird thing is that if I use the match query in a regular `find()`, it works as expected:

```
var query = {
  dueDate: {
    $gte: moment().toISOString() // I've also tried using $date { ... }
  }
};

// finds entries matching the query [..., ...]
Model.find(query, callback);
```

However, aggregating using `$match` and the same query does not:

```
var aggregation = [{
  $match: query
}];

// finds no entries (using the same query) []
Model.aggregate(aggregation, callback);
```

Any ideas why this is the case?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

while using aggregation remove toISOString() aggregate does not work with this

this works:

```
var query = {
  dueDate: {
    $gte: moment()
  }
};
```

Comment: write: var query = {
  dueDate: {
    $lte: new Date() 
  }
};
and then same with toISOString() and you will see difference
var query = {
  dueDate: {
    $lte: new Date().toISOString()
  }
};

Comment: ah, you're right! however, moment() is not working because apparently the aggregation expects a native Date object, so moment().toDate() works in my case. Anyways, it's kind of weird it differs for find and aggregation though.